# Using HTTPS with CloudFront (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Greetings!!

I am using an EC2 machine and running an application in 3000 port in EC2. We have created an autoscaling group and added an Elastic load balancer to it.

I want to use HTTPS connection. Instead of using SSL certificate, we have added a Cloudfront. Cloudfront provides the HTTPS url. In Security group we have opened PORT 80, 443 and 3000

Please help me, is there any best way to achieve this requirement.

I want to use HTTPS connection. Instead of using SSL certificate, we have added a Cloudfront. Cloudfront provides the HTTPS url. In Security group we have opened PORT 80, 443 and 3000

Please help me, is there any best way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Its very terrible design. All traffic between CloudFront and ALB will be in HTTP (plain text!) which is a very big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have an ELB, you can use AWS ACM to get free SSL & attach to your ELB. This way you get HTTPS